# Distinguish between focus loss inside and outside page?

Tags: javascript, blur, dom-events, focusout

A `<div tabindex="-1">` element might have a `focusout` listener on it.

The event will fire whenever the focus changes to another element (or nothing) in the page.

However, it will also fire whenever the containing browser tab or window loses focus. This can be caused by a number of things: `ALT+TAB`, the `WINDOWS` key, the user mouse-clicking on another application, or the user opening the developer console.

When handling the [`FocusEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent), is there any way to distinguish between the event being fired due to focus change within the page or outside the page?

As an aside, [`FocusEvent.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) is available. However, it seems to be `null` both when focus goes outside the page and sometimes when it goes to another part inside the page (i.e. an element which cannot 'receive' focus as such). [`UIEvent.sourceCapabilities`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/sourceCapabilities) also seems to be available, and seems to reliably go `null` when the page as a whole loses focus, but I'm unsure how reliable this would be for solving this problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Page Visibility API to see if the window/tab has user focus

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API